# Objective-C - Loop through all installed applications

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've been trying to use NSWorkspace and fullPathForApplication but this isn't meeting my needs as it doesn't return the correct application.

I could do:

```
[NSBundle bundleWithPath: [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] fullPathForApplication: @"My Application"]];
```

And this will return whichever (I believe) was installed most recently out of:

```
/Applications/My Application
/Applications/My Application 2
```

I want "My Application" to be returned, but the second is being returnd. I don't want to assume all applications are installed in /Applications/ so I'm not just going to loop through a folder.

Does anyone know how I can manually just loop through all applications and verify which is correct? Or a similar method to fullPathForApplication that would return all results, vs. just choosing one at random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the NSWorkspace method you're using is a facade for [`LSFindApplicationForInfo()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSFindApplicationForInfo), which is documented to return just a single application:

> If more than one application is found matching the specified characteristics, Launch Services chooses one in the same manner as when locating the preferred application for opening an item.

If your app opens a specific file type or URL, use [`LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL), which returns an array of matching apps.